# Top Pagination for User Reputation League

Tags: script, reputation, paging

**About**

User Script for cloning the bottom pagination content of the user reputation leagues page and adding them in the top of the user list.

User script created for the "feature-request" of this [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123443).

**Screenshots:**

**Top pagination, if you doesn't have >200 reputation on the site:**

[image: Top pagination, if you doesn't have >200 reputation on the site]

**Top pagination, if you have >200 reputation on the site:**

[image: Top pagination, if you have >200 reputation on the site]

**Installation:**

[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/arulkumar4/StackApps/raw/master/LeaguesTopPagination.user.js)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Leagues Top Pagination
// @namespace   http://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar
// @author      Arulkumar
// @description Moving the bottom pagination to the top of the user list in Stack Exchange Leagues
// @match       *://stackexchange.com/leagues/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
(function ($) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {

    if($('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').length > 1)
      $('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').first().remove();

    if($('#leagueUserList .pager').length > 1)
      $('#leagueUserList .pager').first().remove();

    if($('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').length >= 1)
      $('#leagueUserList .league-container').first().css('border-top', '1px solid #F0F0F0');

    $('#leagueUserList')
      .prepend($('#leagueUserList .pager').clone())
      .prepend($('#leagueUserList .page-sizer').clone());

  });
}(jQuery));
```